# where does VB store its imported namespaces?

Tags: vb.net, namespaces

VB has a feature that C# does not, imported namespaces at a project level (My Project>References>Imported Namespaces). When new people check projects out of source control none of our custom imports are included. Where is this VB specific Imported Namespaces stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is stored in the `.vbproj` file, in the following XML:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Import Include="Microsoft.VisualBasic" />
    <Import Include="System" />
    <Import Include="System.Collections" />
    <Import Include="System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Import Include="System.Data" />
    <Import Include="System.Diagnostics" />
    <Import Include="System.Linq" />
    <Import Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Is your `.vbproj` file in source control, and up-to-date?

Answer (score 2):

In the project file (if I understand your question correctly.) In your .vbproj file there's an <ItemGroup> that contains a bunch of <Import Include="whatever"> elements.

But since that's in the .vbproj file, then the imports should be there when you check the code out of source control. So maybe I've misunderstood...?